# How to make elementary OS detect only one display when HDMI is plugged out?

Tags: display, hdmi

Steps:
1 - Plug an external monitor in HDMI output;
2 - Set the external monitor as the primary display;
2 - Unplug the HDMI cable.

Result:
elementary OS keeps recognizing two monitors and the windows opened in second monitor are lost now.

Is there a simple fix to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laptop + external monitor issue!](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6685/laptop-external-monitor-issue)

Comment: it'duplicated: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8415/multiple-monitors-not-functioning-properly